# To which object is a local variable assigned?

Tags: ruby

For class variables, assigning `klass.foo = 'bar'` is really some syntastic sugar for calling the `klass.foo=(bar)` method. But if I assign a local variable like so:

```
irb(main):001:0> foo = 'bar'
=> "bar"
```

Then to which object is this variable assigned? Does this also call a `foo=` method somewhere? I would sort of expect this, because:

> [In Ruby, everything is an object. Every bit of information and code can be given their own properties and actions.](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/about/)

In my view, this would sort-of imply one (or perhaps a few) "magic" root object(s), under which everything else is defined (...but perhaps this mental image is wrong...)

I tried:

```
irb(main):002:0> Kernel.foo
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for Kernel:Module

irb(main):003:0> Object.foo
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for Object:Class

irb(main):004:0> self.foo
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for main:Object
```

The same applies to code such as:

```
def foo
    a = 'bar'
    puts self.a
end
foo
```

which gives me:

```
a.rb:3:in `foo': undefined method `foo' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
        from foo.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The quote refers to [data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type). Other languages have multiple types (e.g. `char`, `small`, `int`, `unsigned int`), or primitive types in addition to objects, or objects that wrap primitive types. In Ruby however there is only one type: everything is an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 4 kinds of variables in Ruby: local, instance, class and global.

```
def x
  a = 1+2
end
```

`a` is a local variable; it is not an object but a place where a reference to the object `3` is stored. It also does not need an object to be "held" in (just a local lookup table/stack somewhere deep inside the guts of the ruby interpreter).

Same for the `irb`. (But see the answer from spickermann for more information on how `irb` internally transfers locals from one prompt to the next.)

The quote `Everything in ruby is an object` does not mean that literally *everything* is an object. For example, a method is not an object (although you can have an object of class Method which "points" to a method definition - the actual compiled code). A method call is not an object. A variable is not an object (though it *points* to an object).

Comment: Right; Ruby just works like any plain ol' boring language ... I guess I was reading too much into "everything is an object"... Thanks ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that quote just means that literals (like 3 or "abc") are first-class objects - that is the difference to plenty of other languages.

Answer (score 4):

First we need to clarify some things: Assigning a variable does never automatically generate a getter for that variable:

```
a = 1
a #=> 1
```

But:

```
a = 1
self.a
#=> raises NoMethodError, because there is no `a` getter method defined on self.
```

To answer your question: A local variable is defined in the current lexical scope. When you define a local variable in IRB then the scope would be `main` (an instance of `Object`):

```
# in irb
foo = 'Hello World'
self
#=> main
self.class
#=> Object < BasicObject
local_variables
#=> [:foo, ... ]
```

Comment: Local variables are *never* defined on objects. They are defined in lexical scopes, which are *not* objects.

Comment: What he meant is that specifically in irb, the local variables are transfered into a special "main" object; or they would be lost each time after a command was executed.

Answer (score 1):

> to which object is this variable assigned?

None.

> Does this also call a `foo=` method somewhere?

No, there is no method call involved.

> In Ruby, everything is an object. Every bit of information and code can be given their own properties and actions.

Variables by themselves do not have a specific class. They just refer to some object.

> In my view, this would sort-of imply one (or perhaps a few) "magic" root object(s), under which everything else is defined (...but perhaps this mental image is wrong...)

In some sense, you can say that some local variables are bound to an instance of `Binding`. But the current binding is switched by the context, and there is no god object that holds them all.